# Run android application after downloading sources from TFS in eclipse

Tags: android, tfs

I use Eclipse for android development.
I have downloaded source code using Team Foundation Server plugin.
It is following structure:

root/

```
    MainSource

    LibraryFolder1

    LibraryFolder2
```

After downloading I cannot start it as android application. In "Run As" menu this item dowsn't exists.

BUT

if I create new project as Android Application Project then this menu item (Run As -> Android Application) exists.

I have an idea: maybe I need to:

1.download source code from tfs.

2.import source code as Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace

Please support me how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I downloaded root folder. But need to download each folder separately